# Run 2 Discord Bots in 1 Project (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm coding 10 discord bots for fun, all of these have the same code, (but different token) how can I run all bots with 1 code? Thank you.

```
import random
import time
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

messaggio = "ti sto dando fastidio?"
client = client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "()")
Client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Sono online e pronto ad infastidire")

@client.command() #Invia messaggi in privato ad un utente taggato.
async def infastidisci(ctx, member : discord.Member, numero_di_messaggi = 1):
    for x in range(numero_di_messaggi):
        y = random.uniform(0.25, 1.50)
        time.sleep(y)
        print(f"Messaggio inviato a {member}.  Messaggi restanti: ", numero_di_messaggi - x - 1)
        await member.send(messaggio)

@client.command() 
async def infastidisci_chat(ctx, numero_di_messaggi = 1):
    for x in range(numero_di_messaggi):
        messaggio_fastidioso = "@everyone vi sto dando fastidio?"
        canali = ctx.message.guild.text_channels
        y = random.uniform(0.25, 1.50)
        time.sleep(y)
        for canale in canali:
            await canale.send(messaggio_fastidioso)
            print(f"Messaggio inviato in {canale}. Messaggi restanti: {numero_di_messaggi - x -1}")


client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method:

You retrieve the `token` from an environment variable:

```
import os
token = os.environ.get("TOKEN", None)
```

You execute your program from command line with:

```
TOKEN=mytoken python3 main.py
```

What changed here is you have to define the environment variable `TOKEN`.

Now you can just execute the process multiple time. You can also wrap it in a single command line

```
TOKEN=mytoken1 python3 main.py & TOKEN=mytoken2 python3 main.py
```